# Change CSV output delimiter with Java DSL

Tags: java, csv, apache-camel

How can I change the csv delimiter using Java DSL of the output file?

```
from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&delay=0&period=2000").
to("http://graph.facebook.com/nike").unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson,Map.class)
.marshal().csv().to("file:target/output");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this:

```
CsvDataFormat csv = new CsvDataFormat();
CSVConfig config = new CSVConfig();
config.setDelimiter('|'); // your delimiter here
csv.setConfig(config);

from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&delay=0&period=2000").
to("http://graph.facebook.com/nike").unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson,Map.class)
.marshal(csv).convertBodyTo(String.class).to("file:target/output");
```

not sure the convertBodyTo(String.class) is necessary

Comment: Which version do you use? I'm using 2.12 and there is no CSVConfig. You can just call: csv.setDelimiter('|');

Comment: I'm using version 2.10